# IE7 TD Hover Problems

Tags: html, html-table, internet-explorer-7, hidden

IE is the bane of my existence....

I tried posting this before, but I didn't describe the problem correctly.  I've been experimenting since.

I am rendering a table, and inside that table I have hidden DIV elements which are supposed to pop-up and be usable (e.g. have buttons you can push and content to be read).  However, in IE7 standards mode (in IE8) when the DIV Display is 'Block', it is hidden behind cells on the same TR.  It renders completely fine in IE8+ or any standards compliant browser.  Does anyone know a work around?

Please review the code and example here:
http://jsfiddle.net/Ew9GU/15/

Comment: Added a DocType (4.01 Loose).

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding a doctype like

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
```

Comment: Sorry--doesn't help.  I know I didn't include that in the sample, but it is in my original document...